# Counting line using scanner.next();

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The program is suppose to find the name of the class, and check if the first char of the class is uppercase and similary for methods and constants.
Below is my code:

```
public class CamelCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Input.txt"));
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("Output.txt");       
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.next();
            count++;
            if (line.contains("class")) {
                line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (Character.isLowerCase(line.charAt(0))) {
                    System.out.println("dd" + count);
                }
            } else if (line.contains("void")) {
                line = scanner.next();
                if (Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(0))) {
                    System.out.println("Error at line " + count);
                }
            } else if (line.contains("final")) {
                line = scanner.next();
                if (line.contains("int") || line.contains("double")                    
               || line.contains("String")) {
                    line = scanner.next();
                    if (!(line.equals(line.toUpperCase()))) {
                        System.out.println("Needs to be uppercase");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to count the line number using the `scanner.next();`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**May this is your solution:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class solution {
    public static int count = 0; // a static variable for counting
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Himel Rana\\Desktop\\test.txt"));

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            count ++; // counter incrementing every time by 1
            // you have to do something here 
            // I am printing line
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());

        }

        // result outside of your while loop
        System.out.println("Total Line: "+count); 

    }
```

}

Comment: I need to count the line number and then print it inside my loop once it finds the string that I need and check if it's first character is uppercase or not. Thanks for trying though!